# Is software engineering a sudra's job?

Tags: dharma

Administration belongs to the Kshatriyas,  business or trading is allowed for the Vaishyas, can we classify software engineer's job as a sudra's job?

Comment: +1. Actually,  Dharmashāstras were written presuming there would be no technological advancement so Computers are not mentioned in Dharmashāstras.

Comment: @Aghor that's undersrood...i we work as salve for MNC's so I thought it come under sudras category

Comment: @Servent_of_Rama It actually depends. Even Software engineers use brain and even some do administrative work. So, those who do administrative work are Kshatriyas.

Comment: @Aghori Really?? You got great respect for our Rishis.

Comment: @Rickross Why? It was a plain statement.

Comment: @TheDestroyer ok

Comment: "Dharmashāstras were written **presuming** there would be no technological advancement.." The Rishis were obviously omniscient. so the question of presuming something does not even arise. @Aghori

Comment: @Ricktoss then computer jobs are allotted to which varna by omniscient rishis? :P

Comment: @Aghori In ancient times there were vaishyas or traders who used to do some sort of computing to run their trade. Also, there were mathematicians as well, who also must have been doing some sort of computing. So just being in computing not necessarily indicate a particular varna.

Comment: BTW what is vaishali? I edited assuming that u meant Vaishyas. So if you really meant Vaishali then kindly reedit.

Comment: Computer Scientists/Professors = brahmins, Software Architects = kshatriyas, Software/Hardware Sales = vysyas, Software Programmers/Testers = shudras :P

Comment: @Yogi, Lol if there is no IT you should write funky comments on sand or paper. Don't use S word it's abusive word, do you think every IT guy is like that?

Comment: @CR241 Take it easy man I love IT and I am one of the IT guy

Comment: @sv. so who are you here? Is it your perception?

Comment: @Sv. You said sceintists/professors are Brahmins But both are also work under a company or organisation. When both are offering services to any company then how they become Brahmin since they are doing work as employee under their senior. Brahmin is independent in his work, he never use to work under someone.

Comment: @Rishabh Software Company/Organization = Society. "Brahmin is independent in his work" - he's not, he's very much part of the society.

Comment: @Sv. Company = society.... Not at all. Company hire us as employee in which we work for company as employee. In company there is Senior and subordinate relationship are use to follow unlike society where everyone has equal authority. Long summary short, Employees are servants that work under their boss.

Answer (score 0):

**I can say Big NO, One who working as a Software/Hardware engineer or any other profession is based on their interest and it depends on person to person**. @Destroyer Thanks, "Even Software engineers use brain and even some do administrative work. So, **those who do administrative work is Kshatriyas?**".

In the ancient system of Varnashrama, each individual was considered a professional, depending on his area of specialization, and the society was broadly divided into 4 categories of professions.

Due to the openness & flexibility, there was free flow of professionals across different varnas, as and when they acquired the relevant skillsets. Moreover, since varnas represented professions only, it meant that in a single lifespan, a person could be a Brahmin at one point, and a Shudra in another point and so on. For the purpose of illustration, consider the case of a cobbler, whose profession falls under the category of “Shudra” since his role in the society is to serve the rest of the system.

Talking about the word “Shudra” itself. It is one of the most beautiful words because its etymology in Sanskrit language signifies its wonderful manifestation.

> **The syllable “Sh” is actually prefixed for something which is
>   auspicious. For example “Shubh”.**
>
> **The syllable “U” represents generation, growth & upward-ness. For
>   example, “Utpatti”, “Udghosh”.**
>
> **The syllable “Dra” represents movement. For example “Rudra” (Rudra
>   means the movement of roar).**

When we combine the above syllables, it becomes “Shudra”, which means an entity which is auspicious.

And What I want to tell you was, If we call all Software engineers "Sudra" no issue, However those all use brains to **helps in moving the society in upward direction (direction of growth & prosperity)** but not like Slave

Note: This answer is fully based on my opinion, it may differ (No Offence) and I feel this question is fully opinion based.

Comment: "*I feel this question is fully opinion based*". If you feel like that, please cast a close vote on the question or let the OP know about the question in the comment section rather than posting an answer. You have the privilege.